# Time Series: Understanding how to compute the fitted values of a time series model?

Tags: time-series, fitting, moving-average

I fitted a `MA(1)` model over the data using the following code from the `forecast` package.

`fit <-  Arima(oshort_ts,order=c(0,0,1),transform.pars=T, include.drift= T,method="ML")`

with the following results:

```
Series: oshort_ts 
ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ma1  intercept   drift
      -0.9999    -6.4511  0.0492
s.e.   0.0725     1.3632  0.0455

sigma^2 estimated as 1885:  log likelihood=-297.85
AIC=603.7   AICc=604.47   BIC=611.87

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 1.855776 43.41861 33.92396 -81.63723 299.7366 0.4297086 0.1017127
```

**Question:** I am trying to compute manually the fitted values of this `MA(1)` model based on the equation below and **without** using the `fitted.Arima` function, as I want to ensure that I actually understand how to compute the fitted values without relying on the function itself.

$$x_t = \mu + w_t + \theta w_{t-1}$$ 
where $w_t \sim N(0,\sigma_w^2)$ are i.i.d. white noises

I tried plugging `fit$resid` into the equation above to compute the fitted values but the values that I got were way off that produced from `fitted` function. **So how are the fitted values computed using the** `coef(fit)`?

Data:

```
dput(oshort_ts)
structure(c(78L, -58L, 53L, -65L, 13L, -6L, -16L, -14L, 3L, -72L, 
89L, -48L, -14L, 32L, 56L, -86L, -66L, 50L, 26L, 59L, -47L, -83L, 
2L, -1L, 124L, -106L, 113L, -76L, -47L, -32L, 39L, -30L, 6L, 
-73L, 18L, 2L, -24L, 23L, -38L, 91L, -56L, -58L, 1L, 14L, -4L, 
77L, -127L, 97L, 10L, -28L, -17L, 23L, -2L, 48L, -131L, 65L, 
-17L), .Tsp = c(1, 57, 1), class = "ts")
```